# How do I write a function that loops through a list of numbers (the three sides of the triangles) as well as checks what type of triangle it is?

Tags: python-2.7

1. I have a program that checks whether a triangle is equilateral, isosceles, scalene or invalid. The code below

   ```
   print("Lengths of the triangle sides: ")
   x = int(input("x: "))
   y = int(input("y: "))
   z = int(input("z: "))

   if x == y == z:
       print("Equilateral triangle")
   elif x != y != z:
       print("Scalene triangle")
   else:
       print("isosceles triangle")
   ```

2.Now how would I write a function from this that loops through a list of numbers (organized in triplets) and checks multiple triangles whether they are equilateral, scalene, isosceles, or invalid? I don't want it to ask for keyboard input as well.

Comment: So the list is structured `[laa,lab,lac,lba,lbb,lbc,lca,lcb,lcc,...]`? With `lij` the length of triangle `i` with edge `j`?

Comment: I kind of get what your asking, but not a 100%, that structure looks like it could possibly work.

Comment: but your question is: *how can I do this with a list*, then I ask: *how does your list look like?*. The comment was **not** an answer. It was a request for clarification.

Comment: I was basically saying i'm not sure what the list should look like exactly, but that looks good. It's good as long as the list is organized in triplets which would be the three sides of the triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your **second `if` statement is not correct**. Say for instance `(x,y,z) == (1,2,1)` then `x != y != z` holds, but `x == z` so the triangle is *isosceles*.

You can fix this with:

```
if x == y == z:
    print("Equilateral triangle")
elif x != y != z and x != z:
    print("Scalene triangle")
else:
    print("isosceles triangle")
```

Now it is a bit vague how you list is structured. Based on your question, I think it is structured as `[x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,...,xn,yn,zn]`. In that case you can *convert* it to a generator that generates tuples in the shape of `[(x1,y1,z1),(x2,y2,z2),...,(xn,yn,zn)]`. You can do this with:

```
lengths = [1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,3] # sample list
length_it = iter(lengths)
result = zip(length_it,length_it,length_it)
```

Now you can simply use `for x,y,z in ...` to *unpack* the tuples. Which thus results in:

```
lengths = [1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,3] # sample list
length_it = iter(lengths)
for x,y,z in zip(length_it,length_it,length_it):
    if x == y == z:
        print("Equilateral triangle")
    elif x != y != z and x != z:
        print("Scalene triangle")
    else:
        print("isosceles triangle")
```

Comment: @Tim: no because `x != y != z` is short for `x != y and y != z` and `and` is commutative.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness. now for length_it = iter(lst).  How would I define (lst)?

Comment: @cmlayton: sorry halfway through writing the answer, I changed my mind about the name of the list...

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of lists.

```
triangles = [[3,4,5],[5,12,13],[1,2,3]]
```

Then loop through the list

```
for triangle_sides in triangles:
    x = triangle_sides[0]
    y = triangle_sides[1]
    z = triangle_sides[2]
    if x == y == z:
        print("Equilateral triangle")
    elif x != y != z:
        print("Scalene triangle")
    else:
        print("isosceles triangle")
```

Also note that your if statements are not quite right - they fail on some isosceles triangles. I'll let you correct that.